# Issue in running VB script in random machines,

Tags: vbscript, iis-7.5

I have a VB Script file.Which tries to set the application pool in IIS 7.
This script runs fine on some machines and gives error on other machines.
I have ruled out any admin issues by running same script in command prompt by giving admin access

Following is the VB script code.

```
dim existingApplicationPools
Set existingApplicationPools = GetObject("IIS://localhost/w3svc/AppPools")

For Each oAppPool In existingApplicationPools
                If oAppPool.Name = "applicationPoolName" Then
                oAppPool.WamUserName ="username"
                oAppPool.WamUserPass = "password"
                oAppPool.LogonMethod =1 
                oAppPool.AppPoolIdentityType=3
                oAppPool.managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"
                oAppPool.managedPipeLineMode = 0 '0-> Integrated
                oAppPool.SetInfo                      
                Exit For
                End If
Next
if err = 0 then
  CreateNewAppPool = True
else
  CreateNewAppPool = false
end if
MsgBox(CreateNewAppPool )
```

The error which I get on other machine is `invalid char in line 2 position 1`.

Answer (score 0):

okay so the problem to above solution was The machine need to enable ***IIS 6 management compatibility*** under ***Web Management Tools***